# How can I quickly do a string matching on many regex keys?

Tags: c, regex, algorithm, search

I have an array of elements whose key is a *regex*.
I would like to come up with a fast algorithm that given a string (not a *regex*) will return in less than *O(N)* time what are the matching array values based on execution of the key *regex*.

Currently I do a linear scan of the array, for each element I execute the respective *regex* with posix *regexec* API, but this means that to find the matching elements I have to search across the whole array.

I understand if the aray was composed by only *simple* strings as key, I could have kept it orderer and use a *bsearch* style API, but with *regex* looks like is not so easy.

Am I missing something here?

Example follows

```
// this is mainly to be considered
// as pseudocode
typedef struct {
  regex_t  r;
  ... some other data
} value;

const char *key = "some/key";
value my_array[1024];
bool  my_matches[1024];
for(int i =0; i < 1024; ++i) {
  if(!regexec(&my_array[i].r, key, 0, 0, REG_EXTENDED))
    my_matches[i] = 1;
  else
    my_matches[i] = 0;
}
```

But the above, as you can see, is linear.
Thanks

**Addendum**:

I've put together a simple executable which executed above algorithm and something proposed in below answer, where form a *large regex* it build a binary tree of *sub-regex* and navigates it to find all the matches.
Source code is here (GPLv3): http://qpsnr.youlink.org/data/regex_search.cpp 
Compile with: `g++ -O3 -o regex_search ./regex_search.cpp -lrt` 
And run with: `./regex_search "a/b"` (or use `--help` flag for options)

Interestingly (and I would say as *expected*) when searching in the tree, it takes less number of *regex* to execute, but these are far more complex to run for each comparison, so eventually the time it takes balances out with the linear scan of vectors. Results are printed on `std::cerr` so you can see that those are the same.

When running with long strings and/or many token, watch out for memory usage; be ready to hit `Ctrl-C` to stop it from preventing your system to crash.

Comment: Less than O(N) time? Assuming N = length of string, that doesn't seem possible. Every regex implementation I'm aware of runs linear in the size of the input string (case in point: RE2 by Google).

Comment: @delnan: I think he wants to search less than N keys (regex) to determine the bucket (key) to put the string in.

Comment: I don't think it is possible given the complexity of the modern regex.

Comment: @nhahtdh Matching fewer than O(N) regexes, with N = number of regexes, doesn't appear possibly either, at least not without further knowledge about the regexes. In general, the results of running N-1 of the regexes against some string doesn't tell you a thing about what the Nth regex will do to it. (And even if one could skip a constant amount or fraction of the regexes, it would still be O(N), as that's kinda the point of big Oh notation.)

Comment: With very simple regex, I think it might be possible (the theoretical one), with only */+/?/{n,m}, |, grouping w/o back reference, character class.

Comment: In the worst case, every regexp will match, so it's not possible to do better than O(N).

Comment: Is the array static, are the values the same? If so, a neural network would sound an interesting option.

Comment: To be more specific,the array is dynamic, and I would use a string to check each array key (a _regex_) and get the indexes of all the matches.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible but I think you would need to write your own regex library to achieve it.

Since you're using posix regexen, I'm going to assume that you intend to actually use regular expressions, as opposed to the random collection of computational features which modern regex libraries tend to implement. Regular expressions are closed under union (and many other operations), so you can construct a single regular expression from your array of regular expressions.

Every regular expression can be recognized by a DFA (deterministic finite-state automaton), and a DFA -- regardless of how complex -- recognizes (or fails to recognize) a string in time linear to the length of the string. Given a set of DFAs, you can construct a union DFA which recognizes the languages of all DFAs, and furthermore (with a slight modification of what it means for a DFA to accept a string), you can recover the information about which subset of the DFAs matched the string.

I'm going to try to use the same terminology as the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton) on DFAs. Let's suppose we have a set of DFAs `M = {M1...Mn}` which share a single alphabet Σ. So we have:

`Mi = (Qi, Σ, δi, qi0, Fi) where Qi = {qij} for 0 ≤ j < |Qi|, and Qi ⊂ Fi.`

We construct the union-DFA `M⋃ = (Q⋃, Σ, δ⋃, q⋃0)` (yes, no `F`; I'll get to that) as follows:

`q⋃0 = <q10,...,qn0>`

`δ⋃(<q1j1,...,qnjn>, α) = <δ1(q1j1, α),... , δn(qnjn, α)>` for each `α ∈ Σ`

`Q⋃` consists of all states reachable through `δ⋃` starting from `q⋃0`.

We can compute this using a standard closure algorithm in time proportional to the product of the sizes of the `δi` transition functions.

Now to do a union match on a string α<sub>1</sub>...α<sub>m</sub>, we run the union DFA in the usual fashion, starting with its start symbol and applying its transition function to each α in turn. Once we've read the last symbol in the string, the DFA will be in some state `<q1j1,...,qnjn>`. From that state, we can extract the set of `Mi` which would have matched the string as: `{Mi | qiji ∈ Fi}`.

In order for this to work, we need the individual DFAs to be complete (i.e., they have a transition from every state on every symbol). Some DFA construction algorithms produce DFAs which are lacking transitions on some symbols (indicating that no string with that prefix is in the language); such DFAs must be augmented with a non-accepting "sink" state which has a transition to itself on every symbol.

I don't know of any regex library which exposes its DFAs sufficiently to implement the above algorithm, but it's not too much work to write a simple regex library which does not attempt to implement any non-regular features. You might also be able to find a DFA library.

Constructing a DFA from a regular expression is potentially exponential in the size of the expression, although such cases are rare. (The non-deterministic FA can be constructed in linear time, but in some cases, the powerset construction on the NFA will require exponential time and space. See the Wikipedia article.) Once the DFAs are constructed, however, the union FA can be constructed in time proportional to the product of the sizes of the DFAs.

So it should be easy enough to allow dynamic modification to the set of regular expressions, by compiling each regex to a DFA once, and maintaining the set of DFAs. When the set of regular expressions changes, it is only necessary to regenerate the union DFA.

Hope that all helps.

Comment: Is it equivalent to create a _large_ _regex_ with all _regex_ keys like _"^(key1|key2|another/key3|key4/.*|key5)$"_ to match a search key like _key4/something_ and get all potential matches? Does this make sense?

Comment: @Emanuele: exactly so. However, the large regex will not tell you which of the patterns matched; just that one of them did. It is also possible to do this: `^(key1)|(key2)|(another/key3)|(key4/.*)|(key5)$`; this will tell you which was the *first* pattern which matched the entire string (by examining the captures and seeing which one is non-empty). But neither will tell you *all* of the patterns which matched, and that's where you would need your own regex functions.

Comment: @Emanuele, you might want to look at http://www.complang.org/ragel/ I haven't ever used it, but it's always seemed like something I ought to know more about :)

Comment: @rici: I am also thinking about something similar, but nice seeing a concrete answer. I still have some doubt about the complexity, so I will leave it for other to judge.

Comment: @rici not sure I would want to use that one, seems quite static, but I admit I have to look into it more. What I was thinking is about more along the lines of splitting the _large regex_ into subsets and make them keys of a tree structure. If the _regexec_ time is _O(1)-ish_ then probably in a tree structure I could achieve less than _O(N)_ with a sort of _bsearch_ style.

Comment: @Emanuele, This isn't really a code-review site but I did take a look at your code. The divide-and-conquer is interesting but it will be hard to make it dynamic; the regex compile is pretty expensive. But that depends on real use cases, not artificial ones. It will help most when matches are rare. The large regex construction is wrong (and I got it wrong above). It should be `^((re1)|(re2)|(re3)|...(ren))$` Since you're not using the captures, you can speed everything up and reduce memory usage by adding RE_NOSUB to the regcomp flags.

Comment: @rici Thanks I see, will try to change and see what is performance. Btw, the compile could happen on a separate thread, and might limit its memory usage. Will let know, cheers.

Comment: @rici I've amnded the code as suggested but performance is _usually_ at par or sub-par compared to linear scan.

Comment: @Emanuele: I can't say that I'm surprised. If you really want a solution which works in time proportional to the length of the string, you'll have to try something like what I proposed in my original answer. If you only need real regular expressions, and only need to match, not to capture, it's not very difficult.